# Flexbox not allowing scrollable area after collapsing other part

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a HMI using AngularJS(1.7.8) and Bootstrap in which there is four main panels : the navbar, a small up-left, a big bottom left and a big right one.
The expectation are that the small up-left one can collapse to become smaller and leaving more room for the big bottom left. I was able to do that easily using flexbox. Inside the bottom-left panel there is an area that is supposed to be scrollable when the up-left panel is visible. When it is collapsed the scrollable area is supposed to have enough room to display its content.

That last expectation is what I struggle with. The scroll area is not applying the `overflow-y` style attribute and its height is the whole content even though it is outside its parent (the bottom-left panel).

So far I tried playing around with flexbox, setting each panel as a flexbox, setting height and various other things but nothing seems to work. Unfortunatelly I do not control the content and won't be able to fix its height. Since it needs to expand, setting a `max-height` attribute doesn't work.

[Here is an example on fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/q4r9sbvo/28/)

EDIT :

1. From [@Pablo-Binar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12429514/pablo-binar) comment, it appears flexbox don't work that great with % height attribute. I haven't found anything [in the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax) unfortunately.
2. Also from [@Pablo-Binar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12429514/pablo-binar) comment, one solution is to set a height in `px` to the root node giving flex attributes to the child and to the final one (the scrollable one) set an height in percentage (`height:100%`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

`height: 100%.`

If that's to high use

```
height: calc(100% - 30px);
```

That should do the job.

Comment: This works for the example given but not for the real product. The container's height is in % unlike the example and when it is using % this solution doesn't work.